# If two members refuse to be on the same team, how many teams are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

An engineering group consists of 12 men and 13 women.

If 2 women refuse to be on the same team together, how many different project teams can be formed consisting of 5 men and 5 women?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the number of ways to choose $5$ men from the $12$ available; I think that you know how to do that. Now call the awkward women $A$ and $B$.

1. Count the number of ways to choose $5$ women from the $11$ more sociable ones, so that neither $A$ nor $B$ is chosen.
2. Count the number of ways to choose $A$ and $4$ of the $11$ more sociable women.
3. Do the same for $B$.

Alternatively, you can count the number of unusable $5$-woman groups, i.e., those that contain both $A$ and $B$, and subtract that from the number of all possible $5$-woman groups.

Now you have the total number of ways in which you can choose the women. Multiply by the number of ways to choose the men, and you’re done.

Comment: 12c5 = 792.  11c5 = 462.  (11c4)*2 = 660  And now multiply all these?

Comment: @Imray: No, you want to multiply the number of ways of choosing the men by the number of ways of choosing the women. When you choose the women, you don’t choose $5$ of the sociable ones **and** $5$ with $A$ but not $B$ **and** $5$ with $B$ but not $A$: you do one of those $\binom{11}5+2\binom{11}4$ things. So what two things should you multiply together?

Comment: Oh, so 2(11 4) is 11c4 for each unsociable. The total combinations in which one of them is in it is 2(11 c 4). 
     So now I multiply (12 c 5) * ((11 c 5) + 2(11 c 4))?

Comment: @Imray: The number of ways of choosing an acceptable group of $5$ women that includes $A$ plus the number of ways of choosing one that includes $B$.

Comment: so 2(11 4) is 11c4 for each unsociable. The total combinations in which one of them is in it is 2(11 c 4). So now I multiply (12 c 5) * ((11 c 5) + 2(11 c 4))?

Comment: @Imray: Now you’ve got it. $\binom{12}5$ is the number of ways to choose the male half, and $\binom{11}5+2\binom{11}4$ is the number of ways to choose the female half, so the number of ways to choose the whole committee is the product of those numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: for the women, you can select 5 of the 11 who will work with anybody, or select 4 of 11 plus 1 of 2.

Comment: Can you explain that?